# Awk script, incorrect response of "if" statement

Tags: bash, awk, scripting

I want to ask for help regarding a following problem:

I have two files, file 1:

```
1 apples
2 bananas
3 orange
4 prunes
```

and file 2:

```
1 oranges
2 apples
3 nuts
```

I need to extract from the file2 all the lines that doesn't match file1 (i.e "3 nuts"). I wrote an `awk` script:

```
#!/bin/awk -f 
BEGIN {
   while (getline <hdr>0) {
     a[i++]=$2;
   }
   close (hdr);
}
{ for (i in a) {
    if (a[i]!=$2) {
      print a[i];
    }
  }
}
```

My command line:

```
awk -v hdr=file2 -f script_name file1
```

But the result that I got is just the content of the file2 several times. 
What the problem might it be?

Comment: For each line in the file, you're printing all the `a[i]` that aren't the same as it.

Comment: You need to go through *all* the entries in `a`. If none of them match, then you print `a[i]`. A simpler way would be to make `a` be an associative array, where `$2` is the index. Then you can just write `if(!($2 in a))`

Comment: In the second file, `1 oranges` does not match `3 orange` from the first file unless you're doing some fancy linguistic analysis that you haven't shown.  (_Also, the plural and singular are back to front: `1 orange`, `3 oranges` :) …_)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there are many things wrong with your code (even with the input files).  Assuming the line numbers are part of your input you can try this

```
$ join -v2 -12 -22 -o2.1,2.2 <(sort -k2 file1) <(sort -k2 file2)
```

which will return

```
3 nuts
1 oranges
```

if you change "orange" to "oranges" in your first file you will only get the nuts.

A similar functionality `awk` script will be

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[$2]=$0; next} 
       $2 in a{delete a[$2]} 
           END{for(k in a) print a[k]}' file2 file1

3 nuts
1 oranges
```

note file2 is provided first.

It will be simpler however, the other way around

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[$2]; next} !($2 in a)' file1 file2

1 oranges
3 nuts
```

note that file1 is provided first.