# awk compare columns from two files and print the file 1 column if it is not seen in file2 [Similar post related to this was wrongly asked]

Tags: linux, unix, awk

Eg. file 1

```
"ACCOUNT_ID","CTN","NAME","GATEWAY_GUID","DEVICE_GUID","CATALOG_ID","FW_VERSION","DATE_CREATED","STATUS_ID","LOCATION_CODE","BAN","Market_Area","State","IMEI","HW_MODEL"


"306875",="9404653975","14-052917 14-052917","313A0B72E3E440DD8687BD681E55FB03","0",="000010000010004","FW: 1.04.122, JVM: Oracle Corporation 1.7.0_72-ea, OS: Linux 2.6.33.5","06/24/2014 14:32:38","0",="0003013034",="177046772949","DLS","TX",="351612051721824","Cisco DLC-100"

"306875",="9404653975","14-052917 14-052917","7EED6EE61F0949EE99554D4D4F09E4FE","ACFF000001",="000010901000004","1.2.14","06/24/2014 21:28:17","0",="",="177046772949","DLS","TX",="351612051721824",""

"306875",="9404653975","14-052917 14-052917","D57DAE988A1C482EA3217312EDC7466E ","ACFF010904",="000010907000004","","12/16/2015 23:39:21","0",="",="177046772949","DLS","TX",="351612051721824",""
```

file 2

```
account,ban,ctn,first_name,last_name,device_gateway_guid,device_id,device_cat_id,IMEI,device_fw_vrsn,date_created,device_status,subscription_created,subscription_name,subscription_market,date


DL!813269 , 418069632891 , undefined , MUHAMMAD , ANJUM , 313A0B72E3E440DD8687BD681E55FB03, ACFF010904 , 00010907000004 , 351612054025777 ,  , 2015-12-18 19:45:31 , 0 , undefined , [object Object] , WAS , undefined

DL!782477 , 523266997720 , undefined , SAM , MAURER , 7EED6EE61F0949EE99554D4D4F09E4FE , 0 , 00010000010004 , 351612053801194 , FW: 1.04.122, JVM: Oracle Corporation 1.7.0_72-ea, OS: Linux 2.6.33.5 , 2015-12-18 19:02:27 , 0 , undefined , [object Object] , FLP , 2015-07-29 09:07:22

DL!926875 , 578172109430 , undefined , TRACY , BUSH , C57DTY988A98482EA32173RTY907466E , 0 , 00010000010004 , 351612054481798 , FW: 1.04.122, JVM: Oracle Corporation 1.7.0_72-ea, OS: Linux 2.6.33.5 , 2016-01-23 16:09:21 , 0 , undefined , [object Object] , GLF , 2015-11-06 02:26:31
```

I want to compare the file1's "GATEWAY_GUID" column with file2's device_gateway_guid column. Output should be all the records of file1 that are not seen in file2.

Expected output
`D57DAE988A1C482EA3217312EDC7466E` [Because this is seen in file1 but not in file2]

Eg: if file 1 has 10 records and file 2 has 5000 records. In file out of 5000, 5 records are same as file 1. Then my output file should show that missing 5 column values of file1 that are not seen in file2.

Comment: see this answer for a similar question http://stackoverflow.com/a/35850504/1435869

Answer (score 0):

The different quoting/spacing between the 2 files adds a wrinkle, but `comm` is the tool to use here, with properly prepared input

```
comm -23 <(awk -F, 'NR > 1 && NF {gsub(/^"|"$/,"",$4);print $4}' file1 | sort) \
         <(awk -F, 'NR > 1 && NF {gsub(/^ | $/,"",$6);print $6}' file2 | sort)
```

```
D57DAE988A1C482EA3217312EDC7466E
```

The `-23` option discards lines in common (-3) and lines unique to file2 (-2), leaving the fields unique to file1.